# How to make an non dismissable progressdialog dismissable with buttonpress?

Tags: android, dialog

I have an application that needs to show the initializing progress of a sensor. my progress dialog is set to cancelable(false);

```
 progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
 progressDialog.setTitle("Please follow instructions");
 progressDialog.setMessage("Initializing reader");
 progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
 progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Enter manually", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
         returnResult(RESULT_START_MANUAL_INPUT);
     }
 });
 progressDialog.show();
```

But i DO need it to be cancelable when pressing the back button. and it should not be cancelable by pressing the screen. how can i do this?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just replace

```
  progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

to

```
   progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: this is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just add these two lines of code:

**progressDialog.setCancelable(true)** // to cancel the progressbar when you click on the back button

**progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)** // to prevent closing when you touch to the screen.